# npm start not working for my NodeJs project

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Anyone can please help i'm stuck in npm start command
I'm working on node js with typescript - **Running Platform Windows 7-64**
but it won't start throwing errors

HERE You Can check Files

Log File,package.json,Error Image : https://filebin.net/oebfwc7nln660exp

\NODEJS\project2>npm start

> project2@1.0.0 start \NODEJS\project2

> nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts

Node.js is only supported on Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, or higher.

Setting the NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK environment variable to 1 skips this
check, but Node.js might not execute correctly. Any issues encountered on
unsupported platforms will not be fixed.npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 216

npm ERR! project2@1.0.0 start: `nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts`

npm ERR! Exit status 216

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the project2@1.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-28T19_00_00_536Z-debug.log

Comment: _"Node.js is only supported on Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, or higher"_ What operating system and version is this computer using?

Comment: I have windows 7-64

Comment: Can you please check shared link attached some files regarding error

Comment: Well the error message clearly says that version of node.js only supports windows 8.1 or newer. Windows 7 is older than Windows 8.1.

Comment: So what's the solution? do i need to upgrade OS?

Comment: Yes. Windows 7 was released in 2009 and Microsoft [stopped supporting it in January of this year.](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/windows-7-end-of-life-guide) You need to upgrade windows. Or perhaps, install linux on that computer and use that instead.

Comment: Okay thank you for contact & support.

Answer (score 0):

After setting NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK in environment variables with value 1 it worked on Windows 7.

Comment: ensure you check properly if nodeJS was installed on the machine. then, use node -v with the command prompt to verify